# Identify a Preinstalled Content Type

Tags: content-type

Does anyone know of a fast way to tell through code if a ContentType is one that's a pre-installed one?

Conversely, I want to know if a given ContentType was provisioned by a custom feature / generated by the user through the WebUI.

Sure, there are short ContentTypeIds (like `0x0102`) and long ones (`0x0100<flattened guid>`), but is there any other way?

I'm asking for any version, 2007 or 2010.

Comment: I think this question dublicates http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11090/is-there-a-way-to-see-if-an-spfield-was-created-by-a-user/11093

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.pvle.be/2011/01/is-a-given-field-one-of-sharepoints-built-in-field/

Comment: That uses SPBuiltInFieldId, but there is a similar concept for built in ContentTypeIds, details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbuiltincontenttypeid_fields.aspx. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SPContentType ct;
//set your content type
bool builtIn = SPBuiltInContentTypeId.Contains(ct.Id);
```

Comment: Yup, pretty much inferred from the link posted by @gandjustas, but that's the approach I'll try.