# Print only the used fields in Sharepoint using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-server

I need to print only the column that has been created by me.

```
function retrieveFieldsOfListView(listTitle,viewName){

   var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var web = context.get_web();
   var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
   var listFields = list.get_fields();
   context.load(listFields);
   context.executeQueryAsync(printFieldNames,onError);


   function printFieldNames() {
      var e = listFields.getEnumerator();
      while (e.moveNext()) {
         var fieldName = e.get_title();
         console.log(fieldName);
      }
   }

   function onError(sender,args)
   {
      console.log(args.get_message());
   }

    }
```

But this code is printing all the pre-defined fields along with my field. I don't want the pre-defined fields like 'modified,created,etc'. I want only the coding changes. UI changes are not upto me.

Answer (score 1):

If it were CSOM, you could check the SourceId property (built-in fields have the value `http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3` in it), in order to tell whether a field is a built-in or a custom one, like in the following code snippet:

```
SPListItem item = //some code retrieval

var customFields = item.Fields.Cast<SPField>().Where(field => field.SourceId.IndexOf("http", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == -1));
```

In JSOM however the SourceId property is not directly available, so you have to resort to looking into the xml schema, like this:

```
// the rest of your code omitted for brevity
while (e.moveNext()) {
  var field = e.get_current();
  var schema = field.get_schemaXml();
  if (/SourceID="http/i.test(schema)){
      console.log("custom field found:" + field.get_title());
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please correct the code. This is a new concept for me. It seems something wrong with If part.

Comment: I don't see any problem with the if statement. It's a regular expression match test

Comment: This code again displays all the fields in my list:-(

Answer (score 1):

In fact the [similar question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11090/is-there-a-way-to-see-if-an-spfield-was-created-by-a-user) has already been [answered here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/11092/10610)

Below is provided the examples for the case of JSOM API.

At least two options are available to determine whether field is *system* or *user-defined*

### Using `SourceId` property of a Field

For system fields it's value is set to `http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3`

Note: [SP.Field object](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11090/is-there-a-way-to-see-if-an-spfield-was-created-by-a-user) does **not** expose `SourceId` property, but it could be extracted from  [SP.Field.schemaXml property](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/11092/10610) as demonstrated below:

```
function getListFields(listTitle,success,error){

   var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var web = context.get_web();
   var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
   var fields = list.get_fields();
   context.load(fields);
   context.executeQueryAsync(
      function(){
          success(fields);
      },
      error);
}




//Usage
getListFields('Pages',
   function(fields) {
      //get only user defined fields
      var userDefinedFields = fields.get_data().filter(function(f){
          var schema = f.get_schemaXml();
          if (schema.indexOf('SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3"') === -1){
              return f;
          }
      });

      //print user defined fields title
      userDefinedFields.forEach(function(f){
          console.log(f.get_title()); 
      });
   },
   function(sender,args)
   {
      console.log(args.get_message());
   });
```

### Using `Field.FromBaseType` property

> [SP.Field.fromBaseType property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245458.aspx) indicates whether the field
>   derives from a base field type, for *system fields* it returns true

```
 getListFields('Contacts',
   function(fields) {
      //get only user defined fields
      var userDefinedFields = fields.get_data().filter(function(f){
          if (!f.get_fromBaseType()){
              return f;
          }
      });

      //print user defined fields title
      userDefinedFields.forEach(function(f){
          console.log(f.get_title()); 
      });
   },
   function(sender,args)
   {
      console.log(args.get_message());
   });
```

> Note: Personally i find **option 1** as **more reliable** way to determine
>   whether field is *system* or *user-defined*