# Get only visible Fields from Query?

Tags: 2013, csom

I use a simple CAML-Query to retrieve the contents of a list inside the Appweb. (But this isn't app-specific)

```
camlQuery.ViewXml = string.Format("<View><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value></Contains></Where></Query></View>", title);
 ListItemCollection items = currentList.GetItems(query);
                    clientContext.Load(items);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

I retrieve the content accessing `items.FieldValues`. While I get the content I want I also retrieve about 40 System-Values Like "WorkflowVersion, InstanceID" etc. that a normal user cannot see.

Because items.FieldValues is a simple Dictionary there is no Flag like "isSystemField" or something like that.

How can I make sure to only retrieve the fields that a normal user would see when accessing the list in the Backend?

Using ViewFields is not sufficant for this purpose as I need a more generic approach.

*Update*:
I modified [this solution](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11090/is-there-a-way-to-see-if-an-spfield-was-created-by-a-user)  by checking the tables fields and compare the result with my items:

```
foreach (var field in currentList.Fields) {
    if (!field.FromBaseType)
    {
       // do your action for "valuable" fields (non-system)
    }
}
```

This reduces the number of system fields, but there are still about 10 Fields left.

Comment: Have you tried [specifying `ViewFields`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms442073.aspx)?

Comment: Thats no valid solution for me in this case as I want to use this as a generic method for any list.

Comment: Could you add that detail to your question? That's a pretty significant one.